# has no method 'has'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, client-side

The attributes of the model...

```
attributes: Object
    array: Array[1]
    id: "ef93fcc0d431d1000003"
    state: "new"
```

I'm setting... The only difference I made is adding another value to the array.

```
model =
    array: Array[2]
    id: "ef93fcc0d431d1000003"
    state: "new"
    __proto__: Object
```

I augment the array like so...

```
new_array = model.get('array').slice()
new_array.push new_value
model.set({array: new_array})
```

full error...

```
Object function (obj) { return new wrapper(obj); } has no method 'has'
```

This is the bit of Backbone.js that throws it...

```
  // Update attributes.
  for (attr in attrs) {
    val = attrs[attr];
    if (!_.isEqual(now[attr], val)) delete escaped[attr];
    options.unset ? delete now[attr] : now[attr] = val;
    delete this._changed[attr];
    if (!_.isEqual(prev[attr], val) || (_.has(now, attr) != _.has(prev, attr))) {
        Uncaught TypeError: Object function (obj) { return new wrapper(obj); } has no method 'has'
      this._changed[attr] = val;
    }
  }
```

This is an update being sent from the server.

**Just looking for some ideas or direction for figuring out what would cause this error.**

THANKS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your code refers to [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#has). Perhaps that's missing?

Comment: `_ = function (obj) { return new wrapper(obj); }` When I log it, what could of happened to it?

Comment: Oh i see, awesome, I updated backbone to 0.9 and forgot to update underscore.  Updating solved the problem!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was trying to use the latest version of Backbone-relational in combination with an old version of Backbone.js. Updating Backbone from v0.9.1 to 0.9.2 fixed it right up.